# Mac doesn't display picture of UVC camera / microscope

Tags: camera, driver

I've got some [UVC (USB video class)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_video_device_class) microscopes which work flawlessly under Windows and even under Raspberrian on a Raspberry Pi Zero W (on the Pi Zero W, the output of `lsusb` is: `Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1b3f:2002 Generalplus Technology Inc. 808 Camera`).

Under macOS Big Sur, however, it only shows a blank screen, no matter which software I use (I've tried Debut, Plugable's Digital Viewer and also Photo Booth, OBS and Quicktime), although System information recognises it as UVC Camera.

Tried 3 different Macs, all running Big Sur. Could someone please point me in a direction where to look for a solution. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Which macOS version is installed on the Macs you have tested? Is the microscope directly connected to the Mac with a USB cable, or are USB hubs or adapters involved? Which software exactly have you tried?

Comment: All Mac were running Big Sur. I tested different microscope apps like debut, plugable viewer. Also photo booth, obs, quicktime etc. I also hooked it up to a usb2 hub, connected it directly via usb3 and usb2. Always with the same outcome.